# Method reference : Function interface

Tags: java, java-8, method-reference

I have following piece of code that I have been working on to understand method reference.

```
private static String s;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    LambdaTut lamTut = new LambdaTut();
    Function<String, Integer> lenghthFunction = (a) -> a.length();
    lamTut.funtionTut(LambdaTut::stringLength);

}


public int stringLength() {
    System.out.println(s);
    return s.length();
}
public <T, S> void funtionTut(Function<T, S> function) {
    Function<T, String> sqFunction = function.andThen(a -> "Length:" + a);
    System.out.println(sqFunction.compose((a) -> (T) ("Name:" + a)).apply("Demo"));
}
```

1. When i am using `Lambdatut::stringLength`, I'm getting a class cast exception where as `String::length` works fine. I was confused here how the `length()` function is substituted for method in function interface `S apply(T obj)`
2. If I use `lamTut::stringLength`, I get a compile time exception:

   > The method funtionTut(Function) in the type LambdaTut is not applicable for the arguments (lamTut::stringLength)

Comment: You are messing up your types: `LabmdaTut::stringLength` is a `Function<LambdaTut, Integer>`, not `Function<String, Integer>` like you seem to expect. You will also want to describe what you expect it to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`stringLength()` doesn't take anything as argument, and is a method of `LambdaTut`. So `LabmdaTut::stringLength` is inferred as a `Function<LambdaTut, Integer>`.

So the generic type T in your call to `funtionTut()`, is LambdaTut. And you're casting the expression `("Name:" + a)` to T, although T is LambdaTut. That can't possibly be correct.

By the way, since you're casting a String to T, that means the only possible types of T are String, Object, Serializable, etc., and that the generic type T shouldn't even exist. The method should be declared as

```
public <S> void funtionTut(Function<String, S> function)
```

Regarding `lamTut::stringLength`, since `stringLength()` doesn't take any argument, it's a function that takes nothing as input, and returns an Integer. So it can be inferred as a `Supplier<Integer>`, but not as a Function, since a Function needs an input.

Comment: Regarding your last point:  Function<String,Integer> fucntion= String::length; //Works
Supplier<Integer> sup=String::length; //Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method length() from the type String
I was confused with the above case, as length() in String class also does not take any input but returns an integer

Comment: It takes an input: `this`. I.e. any instance method is in fact a function that takes `this` as argument, i.e. the string on which the method is called. `String.length()`, once expressed as a function, is equivalent to `int length(String s)`. If you write `String::length` as a lambda, you get `(String s) -> s.length()`. If you write `lambdaTut::stringLength` as a lambda, you get `() -> lambdaTut.stringLength()`.

Answer (score -1):

In above code

This method is only return integer using instance string length

```
public int stringLength() {
    System.out.println(s);
    return s.length();
}
```

But using

```
lamTut.funtionTut(LambdaTut::stringLength);
```

functionTut not able to determine data type

Just change your function

```
public int stringLength(String s) {
    System.out.println(s);
    return s.length();
}
```

Its work

Comment: *functionTut not able to determine data type* : it is able to determine data type, otherwise the code wouldn't compile.